# Reputation score for traning data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a machine learning problem (medical image segmentation), where I don't have enough high quality data to train on (and where even experts have sometimes different opinions).

So my idea is to build a neural network on the data that I have and release a test version of the software, that shows the results of the currently trained network.

The users, which (in the beginning) should still be experts in the field, are than encouraged to use the automated solution as basis for there own segmentation (ie they can manually modify the ai segmentation).
I would than collect these human modifications to improve my model.
Because I don't know, how much expertise the  individual user really has, I would like to integrate a sort of reputation system (to weight the modifications).

My idea for that would be classify the image patches  not only with my best model but also with some other models (from development) which do have a higher error rate. But all of these models have a known error rate (on the initial training data). So my expectation would be that the number of corrections a user should do to each model is related to the quality of the models and base my reputation score on this.

Is this good idea or total vodoo math?

Comment: This sounds interesting. To make sure I've understood, if you have two models A and B with A  more accurate than B, then basically a user making more corrections to A than B will have lower weight (i.e. reputation) and a user making more corrections to B will have a higher weight? I don't know what your data looks like and you don't give much detail, but I think it's worth spending a bit of time to formalize it mathematically and experiment a bit with it.

Comment: Correct. The data are image patches (between 1000 and 2500 per image) and their classification.(ie 2 different labels)